# RStudio throwing this error while trying to install Knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to create a R markdown file. As a first step I tried installing knitr.

I got the following message. Can someone help me how to proceed from here ?
[image]

Comment: "503 Service unavailable" Retry soon-ish

Comment: Perhaps change the CRAN server

Answer (score 0):

Installing `knitr` can be quite tricky, make sure to:

- run R as with admin priviledges

  `sudo R`
- update existing packages before installing new ones:

  `update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.org')`
- then install `knitr` **with** dependencies:

  `install.packages('knitr', dependencies = TRUE)`
- you may find more useful information in the console output or [here](
  https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/knitr.html)

I had to install also some packages before running R, which where listed in the console output:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y 
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev cargo libcurl4-openssl-dev libmagick++-dev
```

I hope these instructions will help!